# Get jSON Response for POST

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to send a Request using this code

```
protected void Authenticate(String mUsername, String mPassword)
    { 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.5:8000/mobile/");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", mUsername));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println("this is the response "+response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("CPE"+e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("IOE"+e);
        }
    }
```

I am getting a `HttpResponse`, Is the way I am trying to implement correct ? If yes, How do I convert that response to jSON ?

**LOG-CAT**

```
this is the response org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@2fb67110
```

Comment: You can use my code. It is more generalized. Handling different types of exception also

Comment: I have tried implementing you code ANR !!!!

Comment: you should call the second code in a AsyncTask

Comment: See I updated my code with example AsnycTask. Hop it will help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`

This is what you need

Comment: You must implement the Http code in AsyncTask because it is network code. If you have the Log please paste it in your question and also please update your question with the new code

Answer (score 2):

This will help you:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) throws Exception {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // new
            HttpParams httpParameters = httpPost.getParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
            // established.
            int timeoutConnection = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams
                    .setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            // new
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            // new
            HttpParams httpParameters = httpGet.getParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
            // established.
            int timeoutConnection = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            int timeoutSocket = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams
                    .setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            // new
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new Exception("Unsupported encoding error.");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        throw new Exception("Client protocol error.");
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        throw new Exception("Sorry, socket timeout.");
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        throw new Exception("Sorry, connection timeout.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("I/O error(May be server down).");
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
 }
```

You can use the above class like this:
eg:

```
public class GetName extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
String imei = "abc";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    String name = null;
    String URL = "http://192.168.2.5:8000/mobile/";
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", mUsername));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPassword));
    JSONObject json;
    try {
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(Settings.SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                name = json.getString("name");
            } else {
                name = null;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            name = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
    }
    return name;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String name) {
    Toast.makeText(mcontext, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 }
```

How to use it:
Just create new JSONParse class by copying about class code.
Then you can call it any where in your application as shown in second code.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you need to do

```
  HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
                StatusLine status = mHttpResponse.getStatusLine();
                int response = status.getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the [blog](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/). Hope this helps

```
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
           + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: I am getting Error Code 403 :(

Comment: That means your request is not proper. You need to see in server side why server is refusing the request. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403